# How to set different learning rates in two-stage training - PyTorch

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I am doing two-stage training for my model (shown as the following code).

There are two inputs (x1, and x2) here. My strategy is that:

In the 1st stage, tuning ***net_core*** with x1 only. ***net_stage1*** is a supplement for output here, and will not be used in the stage and final model.

In the 2nd stage, tuning ***net_stage2*** by combining x2 and the output from ***net_core*** based on x1.

Since ***net_core*** was already well tuned in the 1st stage, I want to freeze ***net_core*** or apply a very small leanring rate to ***net_core*** while I am tuning ***net_stage2***.

How can I implement this idea?

Here is the code for the network.

```
class net_core(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(net_core, self).__init__()
        ### code 
    def forward(self, x):
        ### code
        return out

class net_stage1(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(net_stage1, self).__init__()
        ### code 
    def forward(self, x):
        ### code
        return out

class net_stage2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(net_stage2, self).__init__()
        ### code 
    def forward(self, x):
        ### code
        return out

class net_main(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, stage):
        super(net_main, self).__init__()
        self.stage = stage
        self.core  = net_core()
        self.stage1= net_stage1()
        self.stage2= net_stage2()
    def forward(self, x1, x2=None):
        # x1: N, C, L1
        # x2: N, L2
        if self.stage == "stage1":
            x = self.core(x1)
            x = self.stage1(x)
            return x

        if self.stage == "stage1":
            bs = x1.size()[0]
            t  = self.core(x1)
            t  = t.view(bs, -1)
            x = torch.cat((t, x2), 1)
            x = self.stage2(x)
            return x
```

Here is the code for stage1 and stage2 training as an example.

In the stage2, all models are using the same leanring rate. How can I freeze ***net_core*** or use different leanring rate?

```
####  stage1
net = net_main("stage1")
optimizer1 = torch.optim.Adam(params=net.parameters(), lr=0.01, weight_decay = 0.001)
scheduler1 = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer1, step_size=1, gamma=0.5)

for epoch in range(max_epoch):
    optimizer1.zero_grad()
    digit = model(x1)
    loss  = criterion(digit, y1)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer1.step()
    scheduler1.step()


####  stage2
net = net_main("stage2")
optimizer2 = torch.optim.Adam(params=net.parameters(), lr=0.0001, weight_decay = 0.001)
scheduler2 = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer2, step_size=1, gamma=0.5)

for epoch in range(max_epoch):
    optimizer2.zero_grad()
    digit = model(x1,x2)
    loss  = criterion(digit, y2)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer2.step()
    scheduler2.step()
```